# How to find the list of packages needed in setup.cfg while building a wheel package

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, python-packaging

I am kinda new for developing python package. This great [tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) helped clearing many doubts. However there are some open questions that I am not able to find online.

**Background information:**

1. I am working in virtualenv using python 3.8
2. aware of the requirement.txt file including all the installed packages

**Questions:**

1. while developing via `setuptools`, how do I determine the list of packages that I need to list in `install_require` of `setup.cfg`? Don't I require to list all packages from `requirement.txt`? What is the best practice.

```
[options]
python_requires = >= 3.8
package_dir =
    = src
packages=find:
install_requires =
                 pandas
```

2. As I'm reading online, it look like `setuptools` is not the recommended approach to build packages, though it was also listed in this [project-org](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) tutorial
   In the above tutorial, there were four approaches listed:

- Hatchling
- setuptools
- Flit
- PDM

Could anyone like to some source/book/Documentation to find the latest method to build python package, if one is preferred than other?

Many Thanks,